# Using Arabic and Persian in SLD filter?

Tags: geoserver, sld, arabic

I want to create Attribute-based polygon with SLD but when I use Persian or Arabic filter It's not working. 
This is my sld:

Attribute-based polygon
    
      SLD Cook Book: Attribute-based polygon

```
    <Rule>
      <Name>rule1</Name>
      <Title>rule1</Title>

      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>test</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>'مقدار ب'</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>

      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#66FF66</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>


    <Rule>
      <Name>rule2</Name>
      <Title>rule2</Title>

      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>test</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>'مقدار الف'</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>

      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#cc5577</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
    </Rule>



  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you don't need the `'` marks around the literal value unless they are in the data like that

Comment: I try without  " ' " but not working

Comment: can you add a small sample data set?

Comment: Thank you for answer
my data place in sql server